# Why carousel does not work when using v-for in img, vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, owl-carousel

I am currently using the following library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-owl-carousel.

It turns out that when using v-for in img inside the carousel, the carousel does not work, correctly.

This way it doesn't work:

```
<carousel
    :autoplay="true"
    :loop="true"
    :center="true"
    :nav="false"
    :margin="5"
>
  <img
    v-for="item in detIncidente.fotos"
    :key="item.fecha"
    :src="item.path"
    width="446"
    height="446"
    @click="showSingle(item.path)"
   />
</carousel>
```

This way if it works correctly for me:

```
    <carousel
      :autoplay="true"
      :loop="true"
      :center="true"
      :nav="false"
      :margin="5"
    >
       <img width="446" height="669" src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any?3" />
       <img width="446" height="669" src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any?4" />
       <img width="446" height="669" src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any?2" />
       <img width="446" height="669" src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any?3" />
</carousel>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you load the images dynamically, the carousel component doesn't wait until data is loaded.

You can try adding `v-if`

```
v-if="detIncidente && detIncidente.fotos && detIncidente.fotos.length"
```

Full code

```
<carousel
    v-if="detIncidente && detIncidente.fotos && detIncidente.fotos.length"
    :autoplay="true"
    :loop="true"
    :center="true"
    :nav="false"
    :margin="5"
>
  <img
    v-for="item in detIncidente.fotos"
    :key="item.fecha"
    :src="item.path"
    width="446"
    height="446"
    @click="showSingle(item.path)"
   />
</carousel>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this has worked for me, endure days.